# Why is WM_ACTIVE having NULL for lParam (the other window handle)?

Tags: windows, winapi

The documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646274%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says the `lParam` could be `NULL` but I am getting `NULL` all the time (alt+tab from another application, click from another application, click from another thread in same application). What is the condition under which is it going to be a valid handle?

I get this for `WA_ACTIVE`, `WA_INACTIVE` and `WA_CLICKACTIVE`.

I am running on 64 bit Windows 7.

Comment: It will be non-null when the other window is one that the UI thread of your app created.

Comment: Any workaround to get the window handle for a window in a different thread's message queue when my window is activated?